# Add class based on data-atribute and href

Tags: jquery

I have this html code:

```
<a class="infoBox" href="#mnModal">Open modal</a>

<div class="modal" data-modal="mnModal">
  <button>X</button>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

So I want to add the class `open` to the modal when the `href` tag matches the `data-modal` tag.

I setup this code:

First I write the `href` value into a variable and replace the `#`.
Then I want to find the matching `data-attribute` and add the class `open` to it

```
$('.infoBox').click(function(){
  var addressValue = $(this).attr("href").replace('#', '') ;
  $('.modal').find("[data-modal='${addressValue}']").addClass('open');
});
```

Bit it doesn't work :-( https://codepen.io/Sepp/pen/BxqNZr

Why not? Is there a syntax error or something conceptual?
The html markup will repeat itself a few times so it must be based on something like a href tag. I can't just use a class as selector.

Comment: Can't use `${expression}` interpolation in a regular string bounded by quotes. Has to be a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using back ticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong way.
You may better use the `data()` method of jQuery for retrieving `data-modal` attribute.

```
$('.infoBox').click(function(){
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href").replace('#', '') ;
    if($('.modal').data('modal') == addressValue){
      $('.modal').addClass('open');
    }
  });
```

Or if there are several modals with same class name 'modal' you may better use :

```
$('.infoBox').click(function(){
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href").replace('#', '') ;
    $('.modal').each(function(){
       if($(this).data('modal') == addressValue){
          $(this).addClass('open');
       }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The find() method returns descendant elements of the selected element.

A descendant is a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on.

It does not include the element itself.

link: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp

Use this instead

```
$(".modal[data-modal='"+addressValue+"']").addClass('open');
```

Comment: Thanks. I completely misunderstood `.find()` then.